# Booting the pc from keyboard - strange behavior

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, cmd.exe, shutdown

Last month I tried changing the settings of my motherboard (z170 chipset) so that the computer would boot by pressing any key from my USB keyboard. But this setting seemed to work once in ten times so after a while I forgot about it. 
A few days ago, by case, I found out that if I shut down the computer using the usual mode (that is, click on shutdown from the submenu in the start menu) it won't boot using the keyboard the next time, while it will if I run the cmd and type "shutdown -s" 
This makes me think that Windows treats differently the shutdown command from the cmd and the more user friendly shutdown command. Is this true? And in which way does Windows treat them differently?

Note: I'm using Windows 10, and my hardware is composed by a z170 motherboard, Intel i5 CPU, AMD Gpu, 2X8GB DDR4 Ram, I can't remember at this moment the exact models but I will investigate and update the question if it matters